# Use eslint if `eslint.rc` exists and defaults to semistandard

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I use semistandard personally so I installed [Flet/SublimeLinter-contrib-semistandard](https://github.com/Flet/SublimeLinter-contrib-semistandard).
I also installed [roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint)  but set to `"@disable": true`.

Is this possible to disable `semistandard` and enable `eslint` when working on others projects whose linting rules are specified in `eslint.rc`?